# GATE_ Parsing error

Tags: parsing, gate

I have tried to execute the below grammar. But, it is throwing an error.

```
Phase: SvP_updates_featuretype
Input: Macro_Requirement updates_KW
Options: control = appelt debug = true

Rule: updates_featuretype
Priority:20
(
(Macro_Requirement contains updates_KW)

)
:updates_featuretypeFired
-->
 :updates_featuretypeFired.Macro_Requirement_updates = {category = "Macro_Requirement_updates", rule = "updates_featuretype"}
```

Error:

```
gate.creole.ResourceInstantiationException: Error while parsing the grammar (file:/C:/Users/Singo/Dropbox/Gayatri%20Kumari%20Damarasingu/Identification%20Stage%20Resources/GATE-Resources/Processing_resources/main_POSTINGAPPROACH.jape):
    at gate.creole.Transducer.init(Transducer.java:127)
    at gate.creole.AbstractProcessingResource.reInit(AbstractProcessingResource.java:65)
    at gate.gui.NameBearerHandle$ReloadAction$1.run(NameBearerHandle.java:1456)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: gate.jape.JapeException: Batch: error parsing transducer: Cannot parse a phase in file:/C:/Users/Singo/Dropbox/Gayatri%20Kumari%20Damarasingu/Identification%20Stage%20Resources/GATE-Resources/Processing_resources/SvP/SvP_database_featuretype.jape: file:/C:/Users/Singo/Dropbox/Gayatri%20Kumari%20Damarasingu/Identification%20Stage%20Resources/GATE-Resources/Processing_resources/SvP/SvP_database_featuretype.jape:22:2: unknown macro name Macro_Requirement
    at gate.jape.Batch.parseJape(Batch.java:175)
    at gate.jape.Batch.<init>(Batch.java:101)
    at gate.creole.Transducer.init(Transducer.java:109)
    ... 3 more
```

Could not able to figure out how come the macro name Macro_requirement is not correct here. Can someone please help me in this

Comment: Usually it means that GATE framework was not initialized properly. Another option from past: as far as I remember there was an issue when the path to JAPE rule contained spaces.

Comment: @Kumari Can you provide some feed-back? Was my answer helpful? Please mark the answer as correct or say it didn't work for you... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You forgot **curly braces** around `Macro Requirement contains updates KW`:

```
Phase: SvP_updates_featuretype
Input: Macro_Requirement updates_KW
Options: control = appelt debug = true

Rule: updates_featuretype
Priority:20
(
({Macro_Requirement contains updates_KW})

)
:updates_featuretypeFired
-->
 :updates_featuretypeFired.Macro_Requirement_updates = {category = "Macro_Requirement_updates", rule = "updates_featuretype"}
```